# how to filter out a null value from spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe in spark with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- event_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- invited: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- day_diff: long (nullable = true)
 |-- interested: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- event_owner: long (nullable = false)
 |-- friend_id: long (nullable = false)
```

And the data is shown below:

```
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   user_id|  event_id|invited|day_diff|interested|event_owner|friend_id|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   4236494| 110357109|      0|      -1|         0|  937597069|     null|
|  78065188| 498404626|      0|       0|         0| 2904922087|     null|
| 282487230|2520855981|      0|      28|         0| 3749735525|     null|
| 335269852|1641491432|      0|       2|         0| 1490350911|     null|
| 437050836|1238456614|      0|       2|         0|  991277599|     null|
| 447244169|2095085551|      0|      -1|         0| 1579858878|     null|
| 516353916|1076364848|      0|       3|         1| 3597645735|     null|
| 528218683|1151525474|      0|       1|         0| 3433080956|     null|
| 531967718|3632072502|      0|       1|         0| 3863085861|     null|
| 627948360|2823119321|      0|       0|         0| 4092665803|     null|
| 811791433|3513954032|      0|       2|         0|  415464198|     null|
| 830686203|  99027353|      0|       0|         0| 3549822604|     null|
|1008893291|1115453150|      0|       2|         0| 2245155244|     null|
|1239364869|2824096896|      0|       2|         1| 2579294650|     null|
|1287950172|1076364848|      0|       0|         0| 3597645735|     null|
|1345896548|2658555390|      0|       1|         0| 2025118823|     null|
|1354205322|2564682277|      0|       3|         0| 2563033185|     null|
|1408344828|1255629030|      0|      -1|         1|  804901063|     null|
|1452633375|1334001859|      0|       4|         0| 1488588320|     null|
|1625052108|3297535757|      0|       3|         0| 1972598895|     null|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to filter out the rows have null values in the field of "friend_id".

```
scala> val aaa = test.filter("friend_id is null")

scala> aaa.count
```

I got :res52: Long = 0 which is obvious not right. What is the right way to get it?

One more question, I want to replace the values in the friend_id field. I want to replace null with 0 and 1 for any other value except null. The code I can figure out is:

```
val aaa = train_friend_join.select($"user_id", $"event_id", $"invited", $"day_diff", $"interested", $"event_owner", ($"friend_id" != null)?1:0)
```

This code also doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: friend_id: long (nullable = false) ?? how come you have nulls? are they really nulls or text ?

Comment: where are you reading the data from ?

Comment: Hi Zahiro Mor, the null values are from a left outer join previous step which I didn't present here. Sorry about that

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Let's say you have this data setup (so that results are reproducible):

```
// declaring data types
case class Company(cName: String, cId: String, details: String)
case class Employee(name: String, id: String, email: String, company: Company)

// setting up example data
val e1 = Employee("n1", null, "n1@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e2 = Employee("n2", "2", "n2@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e3 = Employee("n3", "3", "n3@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e4 = Employee("n4", "4", "n4@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e5 = Employee("n5", null, "n5@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e6 = Employee("n6", "6", "n6@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e7 = Employee("n7", "7", "n7@c3.com", Company("c3", "3", "d3"))
val e8 = Employee("n8", "8", "n8@c3.com", Company("c3", "3", "d3"))
val employees = Seq(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8)
val df = sc.parallelize(employees).toDF
```

Data is:

```
+----+----+---------+---------+
|name|  id|    email|  company|
+----+----+---------+---------+
|  n1|null|n1@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n2|   2|n2@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n3|   3|n3@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n4|   4|n4@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n5|null|n5@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n6|   6|n6@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n7|   7|n7@c3.com|[c3,3,d3]|
|  n8|   8|n8@c3.com|[c3,3,d3]|
+----+----+---------+---------+
```

Now to filter employees with `null` ids, you will do --

```
df.filter("id is null").show
```

which will correctly show you following:

```
+----+----+---------+---------+
|name|  id|    email|  company|
+----+----+---------+---------+
|  n1|null|n1@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n5|null|n5@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
+----+----+---------+---------+
```

Coming to the second part of your question, you can replace the `null` ids with 0 and other values with 1 with this --

```
df.withColumn("id", when($"id".isNull, 0).otherwise(1)).show
```

This results in:

```
+----+---+---------+---------+
|name| id|    email|  company|
+----+---+---------+---------+
|  n1|  0|n1@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n2|  1|n2@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n3|  1|n3@c1.com|[c1,1,d1]|
|  n4|  1|n4@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n5|  0|n5@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n6|  1|n6@c2.com|[c2,2,d2]|
|  n7|  1|n7@c3.com|[c3,3,d3]|
|  n8|  1|n8@c3.com|[c3,3,d3]|
+----+---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: can you please provide details about spark version.

Comment: Not sure about the exact version. This was a year ago. But I think 2.0

Comment: Works with Spark 2.4.0

Answer (score 65):

Or like `df.filter($"friend_id".isNotNull)`

Answer (score 27):

```
df.where(df.col("friend_id").isNull)
```

Answer (score 22):

There are two ways to do it: creating filter condition *1) Manually 2) Dynamically.*

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"),
  (1, "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"),
  (2, "a3", "b3", null, "d3"),
  (3, "a4", null, "c4", "d4"),
  (4, null, "b5", "c5", "d5")
)).toDF("id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")

+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  0|  a1|  b1|  c1|  d1|
|  1|  a2|  b2|  c2|  d2|
|  2|  a3|  b3|null|  d3|
|  3|  a4|null|  c4|  d4|
|  4|null|  b5|  c5|  d5|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

**1) Creating filter condition manually** i.e. using DataFrame `where` or `filter` function

```
df.filter(col("col1").isNotNull && col("col2").isNotNull).show
```

or

```
df.where("col1 is not null and col2 is not null").show
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  0|  a1|  b1|  c1|  d1|
|  1|  a2|  b2|  c2|  d2|
|  2|  a3|  b3|null|  d3|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

**2) Creating filter condition dynamically**: This is useful when we don't want any column to have null value and there are large number of columns, which is mostly the case.

To create the filter condition manually in these cases will waste a lot of time. In below code we are including all columns dynamically using `map` and `reduce` function on DataFrame columns:

```
val filterCond = df.columns.map(x=>col(x).isNotNull).reduce(_ && _)
```

How `filterCond` looks:

```
filterCond: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (((((id IS NOT NULL) AND (col1 IS NOT NULL)) AND (col2 IS NOT NULL)) AND (col3 IS NOT NULL)) AND (col4 IS NOT NULL))
```

Filtering:

```
val filteredDf = df.filter(filterCond)
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  0|  a1|  b1|  c1|  d1|
|  1|  a2|  b2|  c2|  d2|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Very nice example !

Answer (score 20):

A good solution for me was to drop the rows with any null values:

`Dataset<Row> filtered = df.filter(row => !row.anyNull);`

In case one is interested in the other case, just call `row.anyNull`.
(Spark 2.1.0 using Java API)

Answer (score 6):

The following lines work well:

```
test.filter("friend_id is not null")
```

Answer (score 2):

From the hint from Michael Kopaniov, below works

```
df.where(df("id").isNotNull).show
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for spark in Java. To select data rows **containing** nulls. When you have Dataset data, you do:

```
Dataset<Row> containingNulls =  data.where(data.col("COLUMN_NAME").isNull())
```

To filter out data **without** nulls you do:

```
Dataset<Row> withoutNulls = data.where(data.col("COLUMN_NAME").isNotNull())
```

Often dataframes contain columns of type String where instead of nulls we have empty strings like "". To filter out such data as well we do:

```
Dataset<Row> withoutNullsAndEmpty = data.where(data.col("COLUMN_NAME").isNotNull().and(data.col("COLUMN_NAME").notEqual("")))
```

Answer (score 2):

for the first question, it is correct you are filtering out nulls and hence count is zero.

for the second replacing: use like below:

```
val options = Map("path" -> "...\\ex.csv", "header" -> "true")
val dfNull = spark.sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", options)

scala> dfNull.show

+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   user_id|  event_id|invited|day_diff|interested|event_owner|friend_id|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   4236494| 110357109|      0|      -1|         0|  937597069|     null|
|  78065188| 498404626|      0|       0|         0| 2904922087|     null|
| 282487230|2520855981|      0|      28|         0| 3749735525|     null|
| 335269852|1641491432|      0|       2|         0| 1490350911|     null|
| 437050836|1238456614|      0|       2|         0|  991277599|     null|
| 447244169|2095085551|      0|      -1|         0| 1579858878|        a|
| 516353916|1076364848|      0|       3|         1| 3597645735|        b|
| 528218683|1151525474|      0|       1|         0| 3433080956|        c|
| 531967718|3632072502|      0|       1|         0| 3863085861|     null|
| 627948360|2823119321|      0|       0|         0| 4092665803|     null|
| 811791433|3513954032|      0|       2|         0|  415464198|     null|
| 830686203|  99027353|      0|       0|         0| 3549822604|     null|
|1008893291|1115453150|      0|       2|         0| 2245155244|     null|
|1239364869|2824096896|      0|       2|         1| 2579294650|        d|
|1287950172|1076364848|      0|       0|         0| 3597645735|     null|
|1345896548|2658555390|      0|       1|         0| 2025118823|     null|
|1354205322|2564682277|      0|       3|         0| 2563033185|     null|
|1408344828|1255629030|      0|      -1|         1|  804901063|     null|
|1452633375|1334001859|      0|       4|         0| 1488588320|     null|
|1625052108|3297535757|      0|       3|         0| 1972598895|     null|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+

dfNull.withColumn("friend_idTmp", when($"friend_id".isNull, "1").otherwise("0")).drop($"friend_id").withColumnRenamed("friend_idTmp", "friend_id").show

+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   user_id|  event_id|invited|day_diff|interested|event_owner|friend_id|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   4236494| 110357109|      0|      -1|         0|  937597069|        1|
|  78065188| 498404626|      0|       0|         0| 2904922087|        1|
| 282487230|2520855981|      0|      28|         0| 3749735525|        1|
| 335269852|1641491432|      0|       2|         0| 1490350911|        1|
| 437050836|1238456614|      0|       2|         0|  991277599|        1|
| 447244169|2095085551|      0|      -1|         0| 1579858878|        0|
| 516353916|1076364848|      0|       3|         1| 3597645735|        0|
| 528218683|1151525474|      0|       1|         0| 3433080956|        0|
| 531967718|3632072502|      0|       1|         0| 3863085861|        1|
| 627948360|2823119321|      0|       0|         0| 4092665803|        1|
| 811791433|3513954032|      0|       2|         0|  415464198|        1|
| 830686203|  99027353|      0|       0|         0| 3549822604|        1|
|1008893291|1115453150|      0|       2|         0| 2245155244|        1|
|1239364869|2824096896|      0|       2|         1| 2579294650|        0|
|1287950172|1076364848|      0|       0|         0| 3597645735|        1|
|1345896548|2658555390|      0|       1|         0| 2025118823|        1|
|1354205322|2564682277|      0|       3|         0| 2563033185|        1|
|1408344828|1255629030|      0|      -1|         1|  804901063|        1|
|1452633375|1334001859|      0|       4|         0| 1488588320|        1|
|1625052108|3297535757|      0|       3|         0| 1972598895|        1|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way to filter out null values from multiple columns in spark dataframe. Please pay attention there is **AND** between columns.

```
df.filter(" COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) IS NOT NULL")
```

If you need to filter out rows that contain any null (**OR** connected) please use

```
df.na.drop()
```

Answer (score 2):

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("1001", "1007"),
  ("1002", null),
  ("1003", "1005"),
  (null, "1006")
).toDF("user_id", "friend_id")
```

Data is:

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|friend_id|
+-------+---------+
|   1001|     1007|
|   1002|     null|
|   1003|     1005|
|   null|     1006|
+-------+---------+
```

Drop rows containing any null or NaN values in the specified columns of the Seq:

```scala
df.na.drop(Seq("friend_id"))
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|friend_id|
+-------+---------+
|   1001|     1007|
|   1003|     1005|
|   null|     1006|
+-------+---------+
```

If do not specify columns, drop row as long as any column of a row contains null or NaN values:

```scala
df.na.drop()
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+
|user_id|friend_id|
+-------+---------+
|   1001|     1007|
|   1003|     1005|
+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to solve my question. It works. But as we all know, I work around a country's mile to solve it. So, is there a short cut for that? Thanks

```
def filter_null(field : Any) : Int = field match {
    case null => 0
    case _    => 1
}

val test = train_event_join.join(
    user_friends_pair,
    train_event_join("user_id") === user_friends_pair("user_id") &&
    train_event_join("event_owner") === user_friends_pair("friend_id"),
    "left"
).select(
    train_event_join("user_id"),
    train_event_join("event_id"),
    train_event_join("invited"),
    train_event_join("day_diff"),
    train_event_join("interested"),
    train_event_join("event_owner"),
    user_friends_pair("friend_id")
).rdd.map{
    line => (
        line(0).toString.toLong,
        line(1).toString.toLong,
        line(2).toString.toLong,
        line(3).toString.toLong,
        line(4).toString.toLong,
        line(5).toString.toLong,
        filter_null(line(6))
        )
    }.toDF("user_id", "event_id", "invited", "day_diff", "interested", "event_owner", "creator_is_friend")
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to intermediate rdd and then back to dataframe just to replace nulls. Please see my answer for analogous example.

Comment: Thank you, Sachin Tyagi. I use this code: val aaa = test.filter("friend_id is null"). But I cannot filter out any rows with null values in the friend_id field. I compared your code and my code. The friend_id type is long. Can this one be the reason we got different results?

Comment: Hi, I checked with the long as well and it works same (as expected). Can you please double check your code. Or paste an end-to-end reproducible snippet that can be tested here as well?