# Count empty values in dataframe column in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to count empty values in column in DataFrame like this:

```
df.filter((df(colname) === null) || (df(colname) === "")).count()
```

In `colname` there is a name of the column. This works fine if column type is string but if column type is integer and there are some nulls this code always returns 0. Why is this so? How to change it to make it work?

Comment: In this thread you find more extensive answers. Just add .count(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727742/how-to-filter-out-a-null-value-from-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on the question that `df.filter((df(colname) === null) || (df(colname) === "")).count()` works for `String` data types but the testing shows that `null` are not handled.

@Psidom's answer handles both `null` and `empty` but **does not** handle for `NaN`.

checking for `.isNaN` should handle all three cases

```
df.filter(df(colName).isNull || df(colName) === "" || df(colName).isNaN).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isNull` to test the `null` condition:

```
val df = Seq((Some("a"), Some(1)), (null, null), (Some(""), Some(2))).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: int]

df.filter(df("A").isNull || df("A") === "").count
// res7: Long = 2

df.filter(df("B").isNull || df("B") === "").count
// res8: Long = 1
```